# Rounding X value and Y value for point in the construction

Tags: c#, point, rounding

How can the public Value be different than the private one ?

[image: The private X & Y values are different than the public ones]

Answer (score 0):

Though we have no idea what the relationship it is between the `_x` and `X`, `_x` seems to be the rounding approximation of `X`.

BTW, it would be nice to specify which Point you are using. There are different classes called Point, such as `System.Drawing.Point` and `System.Windows.Point`.

Answer (score 0):

Is point one of your classes? as the normal System.Drawing. Point does not allow for anything but an integer to be passed. Could you please post your code of your Point Class.